# Not a major contributor to Generics. Why not?

Tags: support, documentation, docs-contributors

I just made a fairly major edit to [Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/92/generics)—deleting an example and adding a decent amount of new content. What does the [contributors page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/92/) say?

> net contribution of 404 characters

Yet somehow, I'm only listed as a minor contributor, despite adding well over 350 characters. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only made a 316 character change to one example, and a smaller change to the "Syntax" section.

The [example's contributor page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/388) shows you only made 316 characters to that example, and the rest appears to have been additions to the "Syntax" section. The removal of one example does not affect your status on another example, and does not appear to be listed as part of that change.

> changed 52 mins ago - 2 sections modified, (88, 316) for net contribution of 404 characters

The numbers in the parenthesis show how much you edited for each part- 88 characters to "Syntax" and 316 to "Creating a Generic Class", the example.

I don't know for sure what makes a user a "Major Contributor" at the topic level, as that's not really outlined anywhere that I've seen, but you aren't a "Major Contributor" at the example level either.

Looking at the "Major Contributors" at the topic level, it *looks* like being a major contributor at the example level does it. There is one user that looks like they don't fit the pattern, but they added an example, making them an automatic "Major Contributor" to it. The "Arrays" topic, also in the Java tag, follows the same pattern, therefore this is a likely correct guess.

Comment: I'll upvote this because it's a decent explanation, but I kind of want to wait to see if someone else knows what _does_ give major contributor status on the topic level before accepting this :P

Comment: @SomePerson Looking at it again, the user that appears to break the pattern _is_ a Major Contributor for one example, as the creator of the example. So evidence does suggest that being a Major Contributor at the example level makes you so at the topic level. That said, I'd like confirmation on that as well, so I'm certainly fine with waiting myself. :)

Comment: Well, it's been almost a week… I think you're right about this.